# Creating a simple calculator in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write a simple C calculator script, using only the basic +, -, /, *. I have the following, but I'm not sure why it's not printing correctly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{

    //introduce vars
    double number1, number2, result;
    char symbol; //the operator *, -, +, /

    //allow user interaction
    printf("Enter your formula \n");
    scanf("%f %c %f", &number1, &symbol, &number2);

    switch (symbol) {
        case '+':
            result = number1 + number2;
            break;
        default:
            printf("something else happened i am not aware of");
            break;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the result not being printed? Am I doing something wrong here,

```
result = number1 + number2;
```

Comment: You need a printf("%i", result); before your getchar();

Comment: I see you updated a post with a comment. Can you post your most recent code?

Comment: Note: The above is WRONG and doesn't compute because I declare my vars as doubles, then later on in the code call them as floats. This was a huge issue :)

Comment: excellent point.  %f means "float" and %lf means "double" (or long-float).   None of us caught that. :)  Congrats.

Comment: Would it be suggested to use float over double in this case of calculation?

Comment: Float has the range of about -3.402823 E38 to 3.402823 E38 
(that is 3.4 with 38 zeros after it!  about: 340,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000)  And certainly many decimal places.  The range of a double is even bigger than that.  I really don't think it matters for a simple calculator.  I'd probably go with float myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **"Why is the result not being printed?"**

You calculate the answer properly, *but do not print it anywhere*.

You need to have something like:

```
printf("Answer: %f + %f = %f\n", number1, number2, result);
```

***Without a print statement, nothing gets printed.***

---

**EDIT** Responding to comment:

Did you do the printf **after** you calculate the result?
Personally, I would put the printf just before the getchar();

For more debugging, just after your scanf, I would write:

```
printf("Input as received: number1 is %f\n number2 is %f\nsymbol is %c\n", number1, number2, symbol);
```

If that does not show the input that you typed, then something is wrong with how you gather input.

Comment: I use this to test it and I'm not getting anything. Just 0.00000000 + 0.000000 = 0.000000000

case '+':
   printf("Answer: %f + %f = %f \n", number1, number2, result); 
   break;
Sorry I am trying to understand ;(

Comment: my above error in my code was making it not work with your example. However you were correct and I greatly appreciate your response.

Comment: For `double` types (such as number1 and number2), you need to use the `%lf` conversion specifier: `scanf("%lf %c %lf", &number1, &symbol, &number2);`.

Comment: %f is for floats.  %lf is for long-floats (aka. doubles).
If you use floats, use %f.  If you use doubles, use %lf.

Answer (score 17):

You never print the result...

You need to add something like this:

```
printf("Result: %f", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* I think I see the problem; you're trying to reinvent the wheel. */
#include &lt;stdio.h>
#include &lt;stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    system("/bin/bc");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tater, there's a linux program out there called "bc" that's a really well implemented calculator program.  The code above just runs it.

My point is, you're travelling a coding path that's well-traveled already; you're reinventing the wheel.  Sorry I wasn't clearer.

Comment: i think this was a learning exercise, not paving new roads ;)

Comment: Learning which tools/languages are best for solving particular problems is pretty important too.