# error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'double' and 'double')

Tags: c++, c

I have a program I am writing that lists 100,000 prime numbers.  It works fine for 10 numbers, but after so many numbers they turn into negative values.  I changed the ints to long ints and that did not change anything, then I changed them to doubles and I get the error listed in the title.  What should my variable be?  Keep in mind I am still new to programing.  I also looked at some previous posts and did not see the answer.

```
 int is_prime(double x,char array[]){
 //doesnt use array but I put it in there

     double j=2;//divider
     for(j=2;j<=pow(x,0.5);j++){
         if((x%j==0)){
             return(0);
         }   //isnt prime  
     }
     return(1);// because it is prime.
 }
```

Comment: the answer to this is basically the same as in  [How Can I Convert Float to Int with Modulus in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479366/how-can-i-convert-float-to-int-with-modulus-in-c)

Comment: Eh? `long` is required to go up to at least 2 billion, and the 100,000th prime number is only 1.3 million. If you're overflowing, then your program has missed out a *lot* of primes. `long` should be fine (as should `int` be provided that it's 32bit, which is normal). Compare the output of your program to this: http://digital.library.upenn.edu/webbin/gutbook/lookup?num=65, see where it goes wrong. And check that you're outputting the values correctly...

Comment: @ steve I have made the changes suggested and still have the same results, is it because I am putting these values into a char array[],  should this be something else?

Comment: You really should be using an integer type for prime numbers, not a floating point representation.  I agree with Steve Jessop that you probably have some other problem.  You should try to resolve this --- I expect that your teacher will mark down an answer that used `double`.  FWIW, the 100,000th prime is 1,299,709.

Comment: @spong yeah I figured out that was not my original problem.  When I made those changes nothing really changed, I do not know what is wrong, I suspect a char array[], can not hold the values I am trying to stick in.  Ideas?

Comment: @pisfire: yes, if you're putting the results in the `char` array, that's your problem. The range of `char` on your C implementation is almost certainly [-128,127], so values over 127 will go wrong. `char` means a character, or a byte, or a very small integer. As types go, it's pretty much useless for arithmetic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't use a double with the operator, you must have an int.

You should: `#include <math.h>` and then use the fmod function.

```
if(fmod(x,j)==0)
```

Full code:

```
 #include <math.h>
 int is_prime(double x,char array[]){
 //doesnt use array but I put it in there

     double j=2;//divider
     for(j=2;j<=pow(x,0.5);j++){
         if(fmod(x,j)==0){
             return(0);
         }   //isnt prime  
     }
     return(1);// because it is prime.
 }
```

Comment: awesome, I never would have figured that out on my own.

Answer (score 7):

You have two options:

1. Stick with the `%` operator, then you're required to cast the inputs to `int`s

   ```
   if(((int)x % (int)j) == 0)
   ```
2. Include `math.h` and then use `fmod`:

   ```
   if(fmod(x, j) == 0)
   ```

Comment: `math.h` sure looks like a nice solution, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate question can be solved with `fmod`, but for your purpose of high-value prime numbers, you may be better off looking at a big-integer class, like that at http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/ since what you really want is integer mathematics, and using floats might cause problems as things progress.